# Put WUDownloadCache folder on different drive

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows 10 Update seems to have created a folder named `WUDownloadCache` in the root of my second hard drive. I wonder whether there is a way to prevent it from doing so or to move it to the first disk.